# Wrapping node.js request into promise and piping

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, request

Here is my scenario:
I want to get some external resource (binary file) using [request](https://github.com/request/request) library and pipe it to the client of my own application. If response code is != 200 or there are problems reaching remote server, I want to intercept and provide custom error message instead. Ideally, if response is fine, I want original headers to be preserved.

I was able to achieve that with the first piece of code I've pasted below. However, my whole application is based on Promise API so I wanted to make it consistent and wrap it in promise too. And when I do that, it no longer works. Firstly, I tried to achieve that with [request-promise](https://github.com/request/request-promise), without success. Then I tried to prepare very simple example on my own, still no luck.

**Working example**

```
var r = request.get('http://foo.bar');
r.on('response', result => {
  if (result.statusCode === 200) {
    r.pipe(res);
  } else {
    res.status(500).send('custom error message')
  }
});
r.on('error', error => res.status(500).send('custom error message');
```

**Not working example**

```
var r;
return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  r = request.get('http://foo.bar');
  r.on('response', result => {
    if (result.statusCode === 200) {
      resolve();
    } else {
      reject()
    }
  });
  r.on('error', reject);
}).then(() => {
  r.pipe(res);
}).catch(() => {
  res.status(500).json('custom error message');
});
```

By 'not working' I mean - no response is delivered, request is pending until timeout.

I've changed the code to call `.pipe()` on result passed to `resolve` instead of `r`. It responds to client, but response is empty then.

At the end, I've tried replacing request lib with simply `http.get()`. And with that, server returns file to the client, but headers (like `Content-Type` or `Content-Length`) are missing.

I've googled a lot, tried several request versions... and nothing is working.

Comment: Have you tried .pipe() before resolving your promise?

Comment: What's the point of using promises with pipes? Their purposes are opposite. A pipe allows to not wait for whole response to be completed.

Comment: Yes, it works then. Then only problem is when I want to pipe in `then()` What I really want is to have getting remote resource and piping in different parts of the application and promise would make that separation easy.

Comment: Estus, Im not sure if I understand you correctly but... I think I have to wait anyway because I want to check status code?

Comment: @xersiee Ideally, you only want to wait for the status code, but once it's there and it's 2xx, you *don't* want to wait for the whole response to arrive, just stream it to the destination as the data comes in - so the original approach seems fine to me!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that when `"response"` is triggered, you create a new promise that resolves immeadiately, but the `then` callback is  always executed asynchronously, and when it gets called the file has arrived at the server, and there is no data flowing through the stream anymore. Instead you could just use the `body` parameter of the callback:

```
request.get('http://foo.bar', function(request, response, body) {
  if(response.statusCode === 200) {
    res.end(body);
  } else {
    res.status(500).end();
  }
});
```

For working with streams `request` seems a bit buggy, `axios` seems to do it better:

```
axios.get("http://foo.bar"', {
  validateStatus: status => status === 200,
  responseType: "stream"
}).then(({data: stream}) => {
  stream.pipe(res);
}).catch(error => {
   res.status(500).json(error);
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the hint.  I'll probably go for it. But one small follow up - if what you wrote is true, why everything works in the first example when piping is also done **after** `response` is triggered?

Comment: Can you explain more on why is that code not working? You mean to say that file has arrived even before `r.on('response',...)` has been registered?

Comment: @dasfdsa thats due to the asynchronity of promises, I edited to make the wording a bit more precise

Comment: @JonasW. Thanks a lot again. Let me just ask one more question - does my first working example can be the right approach? I like it more than using `body` because it preserves headers.

Comment: I don't understand your edit as well, maybe because I am not familiar with `r.pipe(res)`. But still, why is it a problem if I pipe it in next tick or after 10 ticks? r is a readable stream and would always be so. I should be able to pipe from it anytime I want. Isn't it? Also, sorry for my ignorance.

Comment: @xersiee: In the first example (without promises), `r.pipe` is called immediately, whereas if you call it after resolving the promise, it will be in the next turn of the event loop. https://github.com/request/request/issues/1990 seems to descibe a similar situation where data is lost before `pipe` is called after resolving a promise. (`request` has quite a few unresolved issues in this area - just look at the number of issues and open PRs in GitHub, I'd recommend considering an alternative.) You also mention that `request-promise` didn't work either - what did you try?

Comment: I simply tried to pipe inside `then()` of the promise returned by `request-promise`. Result was the same as with creating promise myself.

Comment: The solution in this answer loses the benefit of streaming: it first loads the whole response body in memory and only then sends it to `res` which can be very inefficient and is really only good enough if the size of that data is small enough. (See for example https://github.com/request/request/issues/2479)